# AJAX Change HTML Content

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to change the content of a div with Ajax, however nothing happens... could someone help see what I'm doing wrong?

As far as i can see I'm not missing anything, but the buttons don't connect through. I am running XAMPP and apache is turned on.

Index Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <meta name="author" content="Malecia Legodi">
    <meta name="description" content="Reload Website">
    <script language="JavaScript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:green">
    <div>
        <nav>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="home" value="Home"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="contact" value="contact" />
                </td>
        </table>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <div id="content" >
                <h1>Content Review Summary</h1>
                <p>
                    aaa...
                </p>
                <p>
                    bbb...
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer align="center">&copy; Reload Website</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

contact page:

```
<h1>Content Review Summary</h1>
<p>
    ccc...
</p>
<p>
    ddd...
</p>
```

Javascript.js

```
function initiate(){
    content = document.getElementById('content');
    var home = document.getElementById('home');
    var contact = document.getElementById('contact');
    home.addEventListener('click', readHome, false);
    contact.addEventListener('click', readContact, false);
}

function readHome(){
    var url = "home.html";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('load', showContent, false);
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
}

function readContact(){
    var url = "contact.html";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('load', showContent, false);
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
}

//function showContent() to add data into your
function showContent(e){
    //add data to secContent
    content.innerHTML = e.target.responseText;
}

//use the listener to load your initiate() function
window.addEventListener('load', initiate, false);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Where you declared the content variable?

Comment: @ankur, No I'm not getting any error, the page simply doesn't change at all.

Comment: @Amy, adding var before content variable doesn't change.anything.

Comment: Declare content variable globally i.e. outside of the function

Comment: @Amy. 

var content = "";
function initiate(){
content = document.getElementById('content');
...

No change.

Comment: then you can initialize content variable in showContent page.

Comment: Is it compulsory to use pure JS? Why don't you want to use jQuery? It has much better suport of AJAX and much cleaner API.

Comment: @andrey.shedko, could you please provide an example.

Comment: It's better to check their documentation - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. As well as there is huge number of examples in the Internet.

Comment: @user1690748 This code is working perfectly fine. Try reading the browser console when you click on the button. In case it's not working for you.

Comment: I get the following errors in the console:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/New%20folder/contact.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. VM29 javascript.js:22readContact VM29 javascript.js:22
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 
'file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/New%20folder%20(2)/New%20folder/contact.html'. VM29 javascript.js:22readContact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the div id `content` to `secContent"`

Also change:

```
content = document.getElementById('content');
```

to

```
content = document.getElementById('secContent');
```

As well as:

```
content.innerHTML = e.target.responseText;
```

to

```
secContent.innerHTML = e.target.responseText;
```

Your javascript's last couple of blocks of code are exactly alike to an example I was given at college (Although the example in question was only reading a single .txt file rather than several htmls it had the same problem) . I managed to get it to work by the method mentioned above. Hopefully it will help you as well.